# Java 2 ME GameCanvas -- How to receive all keyPressed events?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

Hello
I'm writing simple j2me calculator. using **GameCanvas** class as a basis of my interface. I need to handle both numpad key events and game-relaited events (such as **UP**, **DOWN**, **FIRE**, etc) for moving my cursor. The problem is that neither emulator, nor my Sony Ericsson doesn't receives some numpad and game-relaited events. For example, I get **SOFT1**, **SEND**, **2**, **4**, **ASTERISK** key pressed events, but don't receive **1**, **3**, **LEFT**, **RIGH**, **UP**, **DOWN**, **FIRE** events.

```
class CalculatorCanvas extends GameCanvas
{
    public CalculatorCanvas() throws java.io.IOException
    {
        super(true);
        setFullScreenMode(true);

        cursor = new Sprite(Image.createImage("/cursor.png"));
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(0);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        cursor.paint(g);
    }

    protected void keyPressed(int keyCode)
    {
        System.out.println("keyPressed: " + getKeyName(key));
        if (keyCode == getKeyCode(RIGHT))
            cursor.move(STEP, 0);
        if (key == getKeyCode(LEFT))
            cursor.move(-STEP, 0);
            /*...*/
        repaint();
    }

    private final int STEP = 3;
    private Sprite cursor;
}
```

How can I receive all this events?
Thanks in advance

PS I've found that **Canvas** (base class for **GameCanvas**) reseives all this events, but I have to use **GameCanvas**

Comment: [SOLVED]In your GameCanvas constructor call `super(false);` for not to suppress key events ([link](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/GameCanvas.html#GameCanvas%28boolean%29)). Then you may handle key events as for simple Canvas object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check javadoc for GameCanvas constructor. You should call it with "false" !